# Is there a way to handle ignorefiles (like .gitignore) in python?

Tags: python, git, ignore

I want to write an app that ignores files and directories like git is doing that with its .gitignore file. The goal is the Following. My app is called "MyFancyApp". If I run the cli like this: "MyFancyApp build", the app runs over the current directory and collect all files and put it into a Zip File. But I want to exclude files and directories that i refer in a .MyFancyAppIgnore file. The Code is written in Python

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write a good question for which you are likely to get help.

Comment: You'd have to build this yourself. You could read the file list from the file, store them in a list and when you get to the part to exclude you check if the filename is in the list. .gitignore exists to ignore files when pushed to the origin repository.

Comment: Note that this app already exists: `tar -zxvf my_archive.tgz --exclude-from=my_ignore_file.txt the_directory`

Comment: ...or [git-archive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python library [`GitPython`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/) to check if git would ignore the files by using the [ignored](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=ignored#git.repo.base.Repo.ignored) method. This given a list of file paths will check if git would ignore them returning those that would be. It can be installed with `python -m pip install GitPython` and then, in you code:

```py
import git

flist = [ # list of the files given by glob.glob or otherwise
]
repo = git.Repo(start_dir, search_parent_directories=True)
ignored = repo.ignored(flist)
flist = [f for f in flist if not f in ignored] # Filter the flist
repo.close()
# In your zipping function use the modified flist
```

**Note**

I found that it was necessary to use absolute paths in the call to `repo.ignored` so you may need to play about with `pathlib`.

Comment: It there a solution to specify the .gitignore file , like /path/to/.mycustomgitignore ?

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy In general no - git follows the pattern described in https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore but most implementations of git don't require `.gitignore` to be committed for it to work so you could always rename /path/to/.mycustomgitignore to .gitignore and then revert after the run.